# Specialized Clustering algorithm for Similarity Matrix

Tags: clustering, similarities

I have a (bit of a unique?) clustering problem. Here are the important details:

- The data entities themselves don't have feature representations, but
  there are custom similarity scores [0-1] computed between each of them. So I have a symmetrical similarity matrix.
- It's possible that *sim(A,B)* and *sim(B,C)* are very large, but *sim(A,C)*
  is very small.
- The input size that needs to be handled is not very large, most often on the order of 100s or 1,000s
- The number of clusters is not known beforehand.

I was wondering what kind of clustering algorithm might be suited to these problem characteristics?

Comment: Standard dissimilarity-based hierarchical methods such as single, average, and complete linkage can in principle be applied after transforming your sim to a dissimilarity, for example by taking max(sim)-sim. However whether this is any good depends on the meaning of your data, what properties the clusters that you want should have, and what the clustering is used for or how it will be interpreted. Quite generally without knowing the meaning of the data and the aim of clustering, it cannot be said what clustering algorithm will be good.

Comment: "It's possible that sim(A,B) and sim(B,C) are very large, but sim(A,C) is very small." - This results in a violation of the triangle inequality for dissimilarities. However it doesn't in principle exclude the application of standard dissimilarity-based methods. This depends on the meaning of the data, as I wrote. In such a situation, would it make sense to have A and C in the same cluster or not? You need to decide this; the data on their own cannot know it, and different algorithms will handle this differently.

Comment: You can still use any method of hiersrchical clustering except the so called geometric methods (such as Ward or centroid) which require euclidean distances. However, results will strongly depend on the method you choose. So choose thoughtfully.